# How to disable all inline styling with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Need to disable all inline styling of every DOM elements from a html document.

Saw some solution to override inline styles but i need to clear all inline styling.
Also may be done with the code formatting but not interested with that also,

Is there a way to do this with JavaScript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465158/is-it-possible-to-remove-inline-styles-with-jquery

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
$('*').removeAttr('style');
```

[removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

Comment: @mplungjan yeah Tactical.People read it from [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
$('*').removeAttr( "style" );
```

Comment: why posted answer exactly as mine ?

Comment: Nope. Found it on my own.

Comment: got the same answer early, Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

you could also do:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").removeAttribute("style")
```

Answer (score 1):

for single element or group of element

use

```
$('elementselector').removeAttr('style');
```

for removing from entire page

use

```
$(*').removeAttr('style')
```

hope this helps...

Answer (score 1):

With javascript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName("*").removeAttribute("style");
```

With jQuery (*`my personal choice`*):

```
$('*').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, try

```
$('*').removeAttr( "style" );
```

as it will remove style attribute from each element of the page.