# Remove inline style using jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I tries to use [this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465158/is-it-possible-to-remove-inline-styles-with-jquery#answer-6553745):

Here is the full html:

```
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="test" style="width:auto;max-width:150px;"></div>
     <script>
       (function($)
       {
           $.fn.removeStyle = function(style)
           {
               var search = new RegExp(style + '[^;]+;?', 'g');

               return this.each(function()
               {
                   $(this).attr('style', function(i, style)
                   {
                       return style.replace(search, '');
                   });
               });
           };
       }(jQuery));
       $(function(){
         $('#test').removeStyle('width');
       });
     </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

But I have get this problem:

```
<div id="test" style="max-"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you don't want to remove all styles, just the *width: auto;*

The regex matches *width:*, so it matches max-**width: 150px;**.

Try this instead:

```
var search = new RegExp('(^|;)' + style + '[^;]+;?', 'g');
```

This regex will expects a) the beginning of the string or b) a semicolon before it matches another part of the string.

See also here: http://jsfiddle.net/P5dfz/

Answer (score 3):

**To do it the way you've posted:** just modify your regex to match `style`, but don't match `-style`.

**To do it the right way:** you can simply use:

```
$('#test').css('width', '');
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/t54Aj/) is the simple fiddle which demonstrates use of `.css()` to remove background.

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery's `.css()` to manipulate styles:

```
$('#test').css("width","");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(function($)
   {
       $.fn.removeStyle = function(style)
       {
           var search = new RegExp(style + '[^;]+;?', 'g');

           return this.each(function()
           { 
               $(this).css(style,'');
               /*$(this).attr('style', function(i, style)
               { 
                   return style.replace(search, '');
               });*/
           });
       };
   }(jQuery));
   $(function(){
     $('#test').removeStyle('width');
   });
```

Modified your function please see fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/UA9CF/

Comment: please remove `var search`, it's unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove complete inline style attribute then you can simple use this.

```
$('#test').removeAttr('style');
```

Answer (score 0):

but you asked, how to remove inline-style, so if you want to remove the entire style tag from certain elements in a given scope you can try out something like below:

say your markup is like this:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div style="background-color:red; width:100px; height:100px" >
      <div style="background-color:green; width:50px; height:50px" >
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div style="background-color:#CCC; width:50px; height:50px" >
</div>
```

and you want to remove style tags of the elements inside the div with id `parent`:

```
$('div',"#parent").removeAttr('style'); //$(selector, scope)
```

or something even simple:

```
$("#parent").find('div,a').removeAttr('style'); //div,a or other element types
```