# how to remove the specific inline style using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**HTML**

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100px;height:100px;transform:translate3d(0,0,0);">
    //Some Content
    </div>
```

Using jQuery, how to remove the specific inline style i.e transform?

Answer (score 76):

You can use [`css`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to remove the inline style:

**Setting the value of a style property to an empty string removes that property from an element.**

```
$("#myDiv").css("transform","");
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6y7r/1/)**

Answer (score 22):

Remove inline style:          `$("#myDiv").removeAttr("style");`

Adding a new one:             `$("#myDiv").removeAttr("style").attr("style","color:red");`

or adding a class instead:    `$("#myDiv").removeAttr("style").addClass("myDivClass");`

PostData: .css() documentation in jQuery.com:

> "...Get the value of a style property for the first element in the set
>   of matched elements or set one or more CSS properties for every
>   matched element..."

.css() don't remove anything... or am I wrong? Maybe you can clear the 'transform' property with something like .css("transform","");

---

Okay, you can use .css("transform","") to delete the inline css property without disturbing the remaining ones, but be careful: it affects only the inline "style" attribute, and doesn't remove anything coming from assigned classes stored in CSS sheets...

Go here and enjoy with all the options you need:
[another Stackoverflow thread about this concern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465158/is-it-possible-to-remove-inline-styles-with-jquery)

Comment: the documentation is right .css is used to set.so we can set transform to nothing.that makes we remove it

Comment: OK, that was my last comment... You are right :)

Comment: This is a better answer than what's in the 'This question already has answers here' suggestion IMO :)