# jQuery: Remove specific style tags

Tags: jquery, css

Our form software generates lots of inline `style` attributes, which I'd like to remove. I know this can be done fairly swiftly with something like `$('div[style]').removeAttr('style')` but unfortunately, I need to keep all `display:none` as these can be shown later, depending on conditional choices.

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465158/is-it-possible-to-remove-inline-styles-with-jquery, I know something like `$('div').css('color', '');` would work but I would need to repeat for `font-size`, `text-align`, etc.

So, what would be a more efficient way (with jQuery, preferably) to **remove all style tags that are not `display`**, preferably in a chaining/one-line statement? I thought about using `:not` but can't figure out how to combine with the above example...

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can remove all `style` attributes but keep any existing `display: none` flags by using the selector you showed, then detecting the `display: none` and reasserting it after removing the style:

```
$("div[style]").each(function() {
    var hide = this.style.display === "none";
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
    if (hide) {
        this.style.display = "none";
    }
});
```

Or more generally, keeping the `display` property regardless of its value:

```
$("div[style]").each(function() {
    var display = this.style.display;
    $(this).removeAttr("style");
    this.style.display = display;
});
```

---

Complete example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2Tr8/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Style Update</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div>No style</div>
  <div style="color: green">Green</div>
  <div style="color: red; display: none">Red, hidden</div>
  <div><button type="button" id="processStyle">Process style attributes</button></div>
  <div><button type="button" id="showHidden">Show hidden briefly</button></div>
  <p>Click "Show hidden briefly" first, then "Process style attribuets", then "Show hidden briefly" again.</p>
  <script>
    $("#processStyle").click(function() {
      $("div[style]").each(function() {
        var display = this.style.display;
        $(this).removeAttr("style");
        this.style.display = display;
      });
    });
    $("#showHidden").click(function() {
      $("div").each(function() {
        if (this.style.display === "none") {
          $(this).fadeIn('fast').delay(1000).fadeOut('fast');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent, is efficient and works perfectly. Thanks, have also amended question to refer to style attributes (not tags).

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is store the style(or styles) you want, remove them all and then set stored style again.
Something like this:

```
 $('.selector').each(function() {
 var keepStyle, $el;
  $el = $(this);
  keepStyle = {
   display: $el.css('display')//use comma seprated css style for multiple style
   };

 $el.removeAttr('style')
   .css(keepStyle);
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
none = false;
if($(selector).css('display')=='none')
    none = true;
$(selector).removeAttr('style');
if(none)
    $(selector).css('display','none');
```