# Adding a class with display none to an element after jQuery hide / show produces unexpected results

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have boiled down the code from a much larger application to replicate the problem.

Adding a class that contains only `display: none;` to list elements after that have been hidden (`hide()`) and then shown (`show()`) leaves the element with a `style="display: list-element;"` and leaves those elements visible because the inline style overrides the classes. A working example can be found here - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/x5bpjogj/2/ You'll want to view the browser's console to see the changes to the DOM as shown here -

[image: DOM output]

Here is the CSS -

```
.anchor-control-hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is the JavaScript / jQuery -

```
var anchor = 'F1';
$('[data-anchor="'+anchor+'"]').find('.anchor-control').hide().show(); // this is done to replicate the problem
setAnchorControlButtons(anchor);

function setAnchorControlButtons(anchor){
  state = $('[data-anchor="'+anchor+'"]').attr('data-status');
  $('[data-anchor="'+anchor+'"]').find('.anchor-control').addClass('anchor-control-hidden');
  if( $('[data-anchor="'+anchor+'"]').attr('data-ahv') == 'null' ) {
      var ahvExists = false;
  } else {
      var ahvExists = true;
  }
    switch(state) {
       case 'laid':
           if( ahvExists ) {
                $('[data-anchor="'+anchor+'"]').find('.anchor-fetch, .anchor-raise').removeClass('anchor-control-hidden');
          } else {
                $('[data-anchor="'+anchor+'"]').find('.anchor-rack, .anchor-fetch').removeClass('anchor-control-hidden');
          }
            break;
    }
}
```

And finally the markup -

```
<div data-anchor="F1" data-status="laid" data-ahv="null">
<ul class="anchor-controls">
    <li class="anchor-control anchor-lay" data-action="anchor-lay">
        <div class="anchor-tile"><span class="button-label" style="top: 31%;">Lay</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="anchor-control anchor-drop" data-action="anchor-drop">
        <div class="anchor-tile"><span class="button-label" style="top: 31%;">Drop</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="anchor-control anchor-fetch" data-action="anchor-fetch">
        <div class="anchor-tile"><span class="button-label" style="top: 31%;">Fetch</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="anchor-control anchor-raise" data-action="anchor-raise">
        <div class="anchor-tile"><span class="button-label" style="top: 31%;">Raise</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="anchor-control anchor-retrieve" data-action="anchor-retrieve">
        <div class="anchor-tile"><span class="button-label" style="top: 31%;">Retrieve</span>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="anchor-control anchor-rack" data-action="anchor-rack">
        <div class="anchor-tile"><span class="button-label" style="top: 31%;">Rack</span>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I have stripped away all of the irrelevant CSS and markup. In the example only two of the list items (rack and fetch) should be visible. Changing the `data-ahv` attribute on the `div` should result in only two list items (raise and fetch) to be displayed.

I have tried removing the style attribute from the list item and that results in other odd behavior. Do I need to quit using `hide()` and `show()` in favor of explicit classes or can this issue be solved in some other way?

Comment: based on this answer [http://stackoverflow.com/a/6553745/2359055](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6553745/2359055) it seems you can just add .css('display', '') like this [http://jsfiddle.net/x5bpjogj/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/x5bpjogj/4/)

Comment: That is one of the methods I tried previously and it has odd side-effects too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the code base had to be refactored and the use of `.hide()` and `.show()` had to be removed in favor of classes that apply the `display` property more explicitly. This allows the behavior to be more predictable and for further functions to be added to the project with as little pain as possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('[data-anchor="'+anchor+'"]').find('.anchor-control').hide().show().removeAttr('style');
```

I have updated your fiddle. I didn't see any odd behavior by adding `removeAttr`.

Comment: That works for the fiddle as that line was added to replicate the overall issue. Using `removeAttr()` does produce other odd behavior in the scheme of the overall application. It doesn't resolve the question of why the style attribute is still there.

Comment: It's irrelevant to the question at hand - but removing the style attribute causes other JavaScript/jQuery actions needing to modify the style attribute to fail.

Comment: Then you can define another class to `display` as `block` or what you want or add it in style attribute. Have you tried it? What exactly you want to keep in style attribute after show hiding?

Comment: I have tried dozen's of things over the past couple of days including being very explicit about setting `style=""` or creating other classes to replace `hide()` and `show()`. Sometimes the style tag is used to facilitate other events that jQuery might do - like fades or other animations. If you remove the style attribute it is no longer available to those events.

Comment: If we remove show hide methods it doesn't add style attribute and that is required. Why do you need to show hide?

Comment: The way that I have done it here replicates the problem. In the actual application these list items can be shown or hidden for many reasons.

Comment: I think you should use custom classes instead of show hide.

Comment: I tend to agree which means that hundreds of lines of existing code (the application existed before I inherited it) will have to be re-factored.