# How to remove inline style css using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm attempting to remove the inline style beside dropdown-menu attribute.

```
<ul role="menu" class=" dropdown-menu" style="display: none;">
```

I tried using `jQuery(".dropdown-menu").removeAttr("style");` but it won't remove. What other way to remove this inline display none?

Please refer to the attached image

[image]

Comment: what codes are you tried ??

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465158/is-it-possible-to-remove-inline-styles-with-jquery

Comment: give me a minute I'll attached the screenshot

Comment: Please attached image

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.removeAttr()` for this

```
$('.dropdown-menu').removeAttr('style');
```

**or you want to `show/hide` element using jQuery then you can use `.toggle()`**

```
$('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
```

**or you can use `.show()`:**

```
$('.dropdown-menu').show();
```

**or you can use `.fadeIn()`:**

```
$('.dropdown-menu').fadeIn();
```

Comment: how to remove or hide the toggle?

I tried this $('.dropdown-menu').removeAttr('style'); but no luck

Comment: no, that is not I want. what I want to achieve is to remove the inline style "display: none:

Comment: can you share your code, we want to say what you have tried