# Delete of style by tag and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I delete the style attribute in an `img` tag?

```
<div id='someID'>
    <p>
        <img style="width: 585px;" src="somesrc">
    </p>
</div>
```

Delete this: (just in JS and by tag)

```
<div id='someID'>
    <p>
        <img style="" src="somesrc">
    </p>
</div>
```

I am trying something like `$("#someID p img").removeAttribute("style");` but it is not working for me.

Comment: $('img').attr('style','') would do for you instead of using removeAttr()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to remove inline styles with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465158/is-it-possible-to-remove-inline-styles-with-jquery)

Comment: it doesn't look similar to me. i think they want to remove the entire style parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`.removeAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute) is a DOM method. For a jQuery instance, you need to use [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

So your options are:

```
$("#someID p img")[0].removeAttribute("style"); // DOM method
```

... or

```
$("#someID p img").removeAttr("style"); // jQuery method
```

Both of the above will completely remove the `style` attribute from the element, they will not just empty it `<img style="">`, which could be done by setting the attribute to an empty string:

```
$('#someId p img').attr('style', '');
```

... or, using the DOM method:

```
$('#someId p img')[0].setAttribute('style', '');
```

Comment: Thanks:) I used jQuery method.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to empty style attribute, then:

```
$("#someID p img").attr({style:""});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a specific style (instead of the whole style attribute), you could also use:

```
$('selector').css('width', '')
```

Or in plain JavaScript:

```
document.querySelector('selector').style.width = '';
```

(Assuming you want to delete `width`)