# Jquery animate a div character in a game

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to experiment with Jquery by writing a small game where i am using html div's as game character, so i have this div with id bullet attach to another div with id player, so i have bind on click action to body so that when user click any part of the page body the player fires the button and i am using the Jquery animate method to do that and it works fine except the bullet goes and remain at the top of the page, whereas i want a case where player can fire many bullets at the same time so how can i achieve this. I do not want my bullet div to go and stick at the top.

app.js file

```
//Control mouse movement and bullet movement
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').mousemove(function(event){
        var msg = 'Handler for mouse called at'
        //moves bullet to current mouse position and player position
        $('#bullet').css({'left':event.pageX})
        //moves player to the current mouse postion
        $('#player').css({'left':event.pageX})
    })
})

//Fires bullet
$('body').click(function(){
    $('#bullet').animate({'bottom':'500px'})

})
```

Comment: Good question, I would just add that unless you make this into a working script (by using a code snippet) I would suggest taking out all of the unnecessary code that isn't directly involved with your question. You can learn more about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I hope this helps!

Comment: I can't get your code to work, and looks like your CSS is incomplete. Would be helpful if you provide a code snippet like Jake suggested.

Comment: Ok i will take out all unnecessary code as you said

Comment: So i guess the problem is with my jquery

Comment: I have changed it to a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample that returns the bullet to the player after it reaches the top.  It uses the `done` option of [`animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6553745/903014) to return the bullet.

It is important when the animation is done not to remove the entire style attribute with `$("#bullet").removeAttr("style")` or similar because that would remove the x-coordinate and place the bullet off to the left until the mouse moves again.

```js
//Control mouse movement and bullet movement
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').mousemove(function(event) {
    var msg = 'Handler for mouse called at'
    //moves bullet to current mouse position and player position
    $('#bullet').css({
      'left': event.pageX
    })
    //moves player to the current mouse postion
    $('#player').css({
      'left': event.pageX
    })
  })
})

//Fires bullet
$('body').click(function() {
  $('#bullet').animate({
    'bottom': '500px'
  }, {
    done: function() {
      $('#bullet').attr('style', function(i, style) {
        return style && style.replace(/bottom[^;]+;?/g, '');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#player {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  position: relative;
}

#bullet {
  margin-top: 550px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 15px;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
</head>

<body class="blue lighten-4" id="body">
  <div class="orange darken-1" id="bullet">
  </div>
  <div class="" id="player">
  </div>




  <footer class="page-footer green lighten-1" id="footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <!-- <h5 class="green-text lighten-1">Footer Content</h5>
                <p class="green-text lighten-1">You can use rows and columns here to organize your footer content.</p> -->
        </div>
        <div class="col l4 offset-l2 s12">
          <!-- <h5 class="white-text">Links</h5>-->
          <ul>
            <!--  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
                  <li><a class="grey-text text-lighten-3" href="#!">Link 4</a></li> -->
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
        <!--  © 2014 Copyright Text
            <a class="grey-text text-lighten-4 right" href="#!">More Links</a> -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Woow awsome just what i need