# How can I remove an anonymous inline <style> block being injected with a widget?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm building a site that uses a JavaScript widget to embed a simple form into the page:

```
<script src="//example.com/formWidget.js?id=1234"></script>
```

This then injects the form HTML directly into the page for us to style to suit the site. However, the person who has made the form has included a lot of inline styling that's overriding the site's CSS. I don't want to make every CSS rule `!important` because that's [usually a bad idea](https://uxengineer.com/css-specificity-avoid-important-css/); and it's important to note that the inline styling is **NOT** done on a per-element basis (e.g. `<span style="border: 1px solid red;">`, which is solved in [questions like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2465158/is-it-possible-to-remove-inline-styles-with-jquery)); but as a `<style>` block being injected into the page alongside the HTML:

```
<style>
.widget-form button {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: left;
}

.widget-form input {
  background: green;
}
</style>
```

The `style` block doesn't have an ID that I can selectively target, so how can I remove this injected inline style block? I'm fine using JS/jQuery to solve it, since that's how the widget is being added.

Comment: You would have to know when the style block is injected in order to use JavaScript to solve this.

Comment: @HereticMonkey: That's true. In my particular case, when the external widget loads the form, it triggers a `formLoaded` event. Alternatively you could possibly set up a MutationObserver to listen for a change that matches what you're looking for.

Comment: If that .js file touched your root styles, I would recommended to not use that :D, they should name all classes unique like `.myname-widget-form` not just `.widget-form`

Comment: @l2aelba It's not so much that it's _touching_ the root styles, but that it's injecting its own `<style>` tags into the page, just like it's injecting the HTML. Unfortunately I've got no say over its use - it's what the client is using. But it is something I see a _lot_ with this kind of JS widget 

Comment: I would say that's something that should be discussed in the question and answer as currently it is not mentioned and is a rather glaring elision.

Comment: Maybe just add some class in parent then change your all selectors like `.my-container .widget-form { }` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as the `<style>` block *contains* something uniquely identifiable, then it's relatively straightforward to remove. Using jQuery to loop through all the `<style>` blocks in the page, you can then check their content for the offending selector and remove the entire block:

```
$('style').each(function(index, elem) {
    let styleBlock = $(this);
    let content = styleBlock.text();

    if (content.indexOf('.widget-form') > -1) {
        //  Found an inline style block - let's kill it!

        styleBlock.remove();
    }
});
```

You can also do this in a very similar way with plain JS:

```
var styles = document.querySelectorAll('style');

Array.prototype.forEach.call(styles, function(el, i) {
    let content = el.textContent;

    if (content.indexOf('.widget-form') > -1) {
        //  Found an inline style block - let's kill it!
        
        el.remove();
        // Or el.parentNode.removeChild(el); for maximum backwards compatibility
    }
});
```

Comment: You can just use `forEach` directly on `styles` in modern browsers.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - absolutely. In this case, the client is known for using archaic browsers, so I went for maximum compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

just put it on your css file

```
.widget-form button {
  border: unset;
  float: unset;
}

.widget-form input {
  background: unset;
}
```

add !important if necessary

Comment: Inline styles will always have a higher specificity than the stylesheet; and see my original question about the issues with using `!important` for everyhing. While technically I _could_ add a higher specificity to my CSS, there are around 100+ rules - I didn't include all of them here for the sake of MCVE.

Answer (score 0):

then try this

```
$( "<html>*/</html>" ).appendTo( "style:last-of-type" );
$( "<html>/*</html>" ).prependTo( "style:last-of-type" );
```

the selector changes according to your index file